# How can I get the page from menu as posts?

Tags: pages

I've a one-page template and I would like to get the pages according to the menu order, so I think to have a loop to get all pages from the "primary" menu.

But on "get_pages" I don't have the option to filter by menu, how can I do that?

```
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) to get the items from your menu.

Use [`wp_list_pluck`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) to extract just the `object_id` from each menu item. This is the ID of the page the menu item refers to.

You'll now have an array of the page IDs in the order they appear in the menu.

Create a new [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for `post_type` `page` and pass that array as `post__in` argument, and set `orderby` to `post__in`.

Answer (score 0):

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) should offer what you want and order them by the Menu order set to pages. You can even enhance the filtering to take out specific pages etc.